# Three variable equation using only natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am a high school student that has been working on amateur mathematics for about a year now. Lately, I have been encountering a particular type of equation that I have not yet solved. If I could figure out this equation then I could move on to the next part to solving the conjecture.

$$z = Axy \pm x \pm y$$

You can fill in any value for $A$. $x$ and $y$ are integers greater than $0$.

So for example $A=6$

$$z = 6xy \pm x \pm y$$

Does anyone know of a method I could use to prove that there is an infinite amount of numbers that do not equal $z$. I have been working on this problem for about two months with not much gain.

Thank You

Comment: This is directly related to the Twin Primes conjecture, and is not yet solved (AFAIK)...

Comment: If you would like to, perhaps it would be good to post a question like "what are the equations that specify the different prime pairs separated by gaps of $2n$?" And then you could post your findings as an answer and others could post their findings as well.

Comment: good idea I will need to gather my notes and I will post it soon.

Answer (score 2):

Maria Suzuki found (and subsequently published in the January 2000 edition of American Mathematical Monthly) that the Twin Primes Conjecture is equivalent to the statement

"There exist an infinite number of values $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that for all $a,b\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$,

$$k\ne 6|ab|+a+b$$

" (end quote, variable names possibly changed).

I've worked on this particular direction for a long time myself.  Let me know if you'd like more information on what I've found...

The direct creation of this inequality is as follows:

If we assume that $p,p+2$ are each prime numbers (thus in $\Bbb Z^+$), then the number $p+1$ must in general be divisible by $6$, since otherwise either $p$ or $p+2$ will be divisible by either $2$ or $3$.  So then we have $p=(6k-1),p+2=(6k+1)$, and we also have $p=(6a\pm1)(6b\pm1),p+2=(6a\pm1)(6b\pm1)$ if either $p,p+2$ are composite.  The expansion of these equations results in four equations, but if we take $a,b\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, then they can be rewritten as

$$6k\pm1\ne (6a\pm1)(6b\pm1)=36|ab|+6a+6b\pm1$$

For the equation to be consistent modulo $6$, the $\pm1$ terms must cancel, and then we can divide by $6$ everywhere to get

$$k\ne 6|ab|+a+b$$

which demonstrates the required result.

Note that the prime numbers fall under the equations

$$k\ne ab+a+b\\
k\ne 2ab+a+b$$

for any prime $k+1$ in the first equation and for any odd prime $2k+1$ in the second equation, $\forall a,b\in\Bbb Z^+$.

In particular, if $k+1$ is prime, then there are no divisors of the form $a+1,b+1$ for $a,b\in\Bbb Z^+$, therefore $k+1\ne(a+1)(b+1)=ab+a+b+1\implies k\ne ab+a+b$.  The same logic holds for odd primes $2k+1$ where the divisors must be odd in the form $2a+1,2b+1$.

Comment: Thats very cool it took me only a month to come up with this equation.

Comment: I have some notes that I have made. I am going to look into Maria Suzuki's work. I was able to work out this equation after I realized primes greater than 3 can only be 6a±1.

Comment: Note the question I posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541054/if-n-is-squarefree-k-ge-2-then-exists-f-in-bbb-zx-1-dots-x-k-f-ove  this question covers more general theory in the same vein.

Comment: I am humbled, it also took me a month to get to the same result, but I was already in college and it took me a lot longer than a month to extend beyond setting the constant $A=6$ to some other value...

Comment: This is very similar to all the math I worked out. I did not have the formal education, but close enough.

Comment: k≠ab+a+b  k≠2ab+a+b what do you mean by these two equations and odd primes.

Comment: It is interesting to note that if $A=5$, the inequality $k\in\Bbb Z^+, \forall a,b\in \Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}, k\ne 5|ab|+a+b$ has only even solutions for all $k\gt 1$.  Setting $A=3$ has only the doubles of the solutions of $A=6$, but that is another discussion entirely...

Comment: I've edited to add some discussion of how to rearrange the equation to talk about primes instead of twin primes.

Comment: I mean I mainly interested in when A=6 because I have been working on this conjecture. I have recently been branching out to different A values. This is good to know.

Comment: The formula k≠6|ab|+a+b. Do you know of anyone who has published anything on how the formula can be modified so that it can cover gaps of 4,6,8,etc. I think I have a method would do this. Is this of any importance?

Comment: I don't know about published results, but you might consider modifying the question to look at general polynomials instead...  For instance, this question can be rewritten to ask about the number of two-factor solutions to the polynomial $x^2-1$, and the $4-,6-,8-,\dots$ gap versions are then $x^2-4,x^2-9,x^2-16,\dots$.

Comment: I was asking on a side note. I have little knowledge of much mathematics than what I am learning now and a few thing I have picked up here any there. I am mainly asking about the twin prime conjecture.